# how to add a link to the current class with angular ui -router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to know how to deal with that when angular click on link-ss-1 or link-ss-2, the Link-C is also "Current".

I use ui -router for information.

My example : http://plnkr.co/edit/R5qdRKp6t198MQFjeUYy?p=preview

I would like :

- Link A
- Link B
- Link C ***(--> add Actif class if ss-link-1 or ss-link-2 has the class actif)***

  - ss-Link 1
  - **ss-Link 2** ***(is Actif with ui-sref-active by ui-router)***

Thank you in advance for your answers !

here's the js code :

```
(function() {
  "use strict"
  var app = angular.module("plunker", ["ui.router"]);

  app.config(["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider",
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
      $stateProvider
        .state("linkA", {
          url: "/",
          templateUrl: "content-A.html"
        })
        .state("linkB", {
          url: "/link-B",
          templateUrl: "content-B.html"
         })
        .state("linkC", {
          url: "/link-C",
          templateUrl: "content-C.html"
          })
        .state("ssLink1", {
          url: "/ssLink-1",
          templateUrl: "content-C-1.html"
        })
        .state("ssLink2", {
          url: "/ssLink-2",
          templateUrl: "content-C-2.html"
        })
    }
  ]);

}());
```

this is the HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.7/angular.js" data-require="angular.js@1.3.x"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

  <script src="app.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a ui-sref="linkA" ui-sref-active="current">link A</a></li> 
        <li><a ui-sref="linkB" ui-sref-active="current">link B</a></li> 
        <li><a ui-sref="linkC" ui-sref-active="current">link C</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a ui-sref="ssLink1" ui-sref-active="current">ss-link1</a></li>
              <li><a ui-sref="ssLink2" ui-sref-active="current">ss-link2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li> 


      </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
  <div class="container">
    <div ui-view></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: "how to deal with that" - can you elaborate? Not too sure what the question is, the active class seems to be applied just fine

Comment: so, when I click the links in the submenu , the parent I would also link to the class "current"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using child views on `ui-router`, it works out of the box:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/818

If you don't want to use child views, you can do this by adding a `controller` and exposing the `$state` on the `$scope`, so you can test the current state and add the current class to your links:

```
  app.controller('navCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', function($scope, $state) {
   $scope.$state = $state;
  }]);
```

Change your ui-router settings to:

```
  app.config(["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider",
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
      $stateProvider
        .state("linkA", {
          url: "/",
          templateUrl: "content-A.html"
        })
        .state("linkB", {
          url: "/link-B",
          templateUrl: "content-B.html"
         })
        .state("linkC", {
          url: "/link-C",
          templateUrl: "content-C.html"
          })
        .state("linkC-ssLink1", {
          url: "/ssLink-1",
          templateUrl: "content-C-1.html"
        })
        .state("linkC-ssLink2", {
          url: "/ssLink-2",
          templateUrl: "content-C-2.html"
        })
    }
  ]);
```

And your html to:

```
  <nav ng-controller="navCtrl">
    <div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a ui-sref="linkA" ui-sref-active="current">link A</a></li> 
        <li><a ui-sref="linkB" ui-sref-active="current">link B</a></li> 
        <li><a ui-sref="linkC" ng-class="{current:  $state.current.name.includes('linkC')}">link C</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a ui-sref="linkC-ssLink1" ui-sref-active="current">ss-link1</a></li>
              <li><a ui-sref="linkC-ssLink2" ui-sref-active="current">ss-link2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li> 


      </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Here is a working plunker so you can check it out:
http://plnkr.co/edit/3vWUwe96addTxNduowpv?p=preview

Comment: great, thank you for your help and your quick response.